# ASP.net MVC with IronRuby?

Tags: asp.net, ironruby

Does asp.net mvc development necessarily means c# should be in it? Is it painful to use IronRuby(is it possible?) and how ironruby differs from ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net supports any CLR-languages for the server side (C# and VB.NET). Using DLR languages will require a bit of tweaking as posted by Phil Haak [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/02/17/aspnetmvc-ironruby-with-filters.aspx), and code updated by Ivan Porto Carrero and available [here](https://github.com/casualjim/ironrubymvc).

Differences between IronRuby and Ruby are mainly not yet supported features, and I don't know if there is a complete list somewhere but you can have a summary [here](http://www.ironruby.info/).